# aws cli: how to find kms key id?

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ebs, amazon-kms

When I run the following command, this is what I get.

```
$ aws ec2 get-ebs-default-kms-key-id --region us-west-2
{
    "KmsKeyId": "alias/aws/ebs"
}
```

But what I really want is the key id under "(default) aws/ebs" (shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to get the key ids for all the keys in your account.

```
aws kms list-aliases --query 'Aliases[*].TargetKeyId'
```